# Find the flaw in the P != NP proof

Tags: complexity-theory

Find the flaw in the following proof that P != NP:

"We are going to show that P != NP using the following steps:

---

1. Describe a problem.
2. Show that said problem is a NP problem.
3. Prove that the lower bound for any algorithm that solves the problem is exponential using an adversarial argument (similarly to showing lower bound on comparison based sorting).
4. Conclude that since the problem is in NP but cannot be solved in polynomial time it is not in P. Thus, P != NP.

---

1. Consider decision problem of determining whether there exists a combination of chemicals (a subset) that mix into the philosopher stone from a set of chemicals S[1...n]. We can determine whether a given set of chemicals combines into the philosopher stone using a checking function IsPhilosopherStone(C[1...m]) and this function is the only way to determine whether said chemicals produce the philosopher stone. IsPhilosopherStone(C[1...m]) takes constant amount of time $\theta(1)$ for all inputs.
2. We can show the problem is NP by designing a verifier verifyPhilosopherStoneCombination(S[1...n], w) where w is the witness; the subset of chemicals which produce the philosopher stone as such:

verifyPhilosopherStoneCombination(S[1...n], w):

if w $\not\subseteq$ S[1...n] say "no"

if IsPhilosopherStone(w) != "yes" say "no"

say "yes"

Checking whether w $\not\subseteq$ S[1...n] takes $\theta(n^2)$ in worst case using a naive approach and using IsPhilosopherStone(w) takes $\theta(1)$, so our verifier correctly verifies a given witness in polynomial time so the problem must be in NP.

3. We know we can also solve the problem deterministically in $2^n - 1$ steps by generating the powerset of S[1...n] which has length $|P(S)| = 2^n$ and running the verifyPhilosopherStoneCombination() on each set in the powerset (except the empty set, hence $2^n - 1$ steps).

Now consider an alternative algorithm $A$ which would solve the problem in $2^n - 2$ steps or better in the worst case. Since there are $2^n - 1$ non-empty sets in the power set $P(S)$ and using verifyPhilosopherStoneCombination() to check whether a set combines into the philosopher stone takes 1 step we know there must be at least 1 non-empty set that wasn't checked by $A$. Make that set the set that combines into the philosopher stone. $A$ yields an incorrect answer. This means the lower bound for any algorithm that solves the problem is $\Omega(2^n)$.

4. We have shown a problem that is in NP but no in P. Thus P != NP."

Comment: This is wrong Because you’ve misidentified what the input to the decision problem is. For a hint: the problem mathematically remains exactly the same if you take out the powerset and simply ask if there exists a $k\in[n]$ such that $f(k)=1$

Comment: Are you saying that the problem can be restated basically as a linear search on the powerset? I guess in that case the size of the powerset would be the input size and the solution would run in $\theta(n)$ solution.

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request to check work with no specific concerns raised. We are not a proof-checking service.

Answer (score 1):

I can see some flaws in your argument:

1. first of all (correct me if I am wrong but this is what I understand from your text), your problem can be solved in linear time because it's just a search trough a set of values.
2. Second but more important, your problem is not a decision problem: ***P*** and ***NP*** are complexity classes defined on decision problems.
3. > We have shown a problem that is in NP but no in P. Thus P != NP.

This is were things get confused... your algorithm ***A*** is in NP so i dont get how comparing it with the original algorithm (also in NP) prove that ***P!=NP***

Comment: Please try to steer clear of "Is this P/NP proof correct?" type questions. There are an infinite variety of wrong proofs and there's not much, in general, to be learnt from them. We'd rather the site didn't get bogged down with wrong proofs but, rather, focused on positive contributions we can all make to CS.